# Null pointer when adding to an string array

Tags: java, jsoup

This code works. it prints out the values in the list

```
ArrayList<String> menuItemsUrl=null;

for (int i = 0; i < modules.size(); i++) {
                String tmp = modules.get(i).attr("href");
                Log.d("", tmp);

            }
```

but this one generates an null pointer. why?

```
for (int i = 0; i < modules.size(); i++) {
                String tmp = modules.get(i).attr("href");
                menuItemsUrl.add(tmp);

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you havent initialized `menuItemsUrl`, hence NPE.

You have declared your list here `ArrayList<String> menuItemsUrl=null;` and when you try to access it `menuItemsUrl.add(tmp);`, `menuItemsUrl` isn't refering to anything it is pointing to null which means nothing hence NPE, to get rid of NPE, initialize it before you use.

```
menuItemsUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The null point exception is occur at the "modules.size()" .The modules is a null reference.
Try to instance the modules reference.